# Python Error : File "<stdin>"

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to learn Python and am trying to execute a python file in terminal. I'm using 2.7.3 python version on my OS X. I've changed the directory in terminal to where the file is located, but I'm getting an error in terminal:

```
>>> python ex1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python ex1.py
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The ex1.py file contains:

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thx a bunch.

Comment: Please fix your formatting and explain how you are "trying to execute a python file in terminal"

Comment: if you've never worked in a terminal; try [Command Line Crash Course](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html) [1-2days]

Comment: This question should have been closed originally because *it is thoroughly answered by the tutorial material that the exercise comes from*. (I happen to think that one is a *particularly bad* tutorial, but that's neither here nor there; Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>> python ex1.py
```

You are trying to run your script from within a python interpreter. You don't want to do that.

Instead, just run that command in a terminal, not in the interpreter

```
$ python ex1.py
```

If you are still in the interpreter, you can press `Ctrl+Z` or type `exit()` (+ Return) to leave the interpreter and go back to the 'normal' terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I realized this but didn't know how not to run the python interpreter. I do now..Thx a bunch!

Comment: Yes, how do I "accept" the answer? Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Exit python interpreter by typing `exit()` or press `Crtl+Z`

You will see the terminal now.

Type `python file_name.py` to run the code.

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try type

```
exit()
```

return; then

```
python ex1.py
```

return