# Why This Program is not Running

Tags: python

The Work of this program is if you write a number it generates that number multiplication table
i writed this code in python:

```
num = int(input("Enter Your Number: "))
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(f"{num} * {i} = ", num * i)
    i = i + 1
```

but why this program is not running when i press the run button it throws an error, The error is given below:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Python311/python.exe "d:/My Files/Python Files/Python Practice/Chapter7_Q1.py
  File "<stdin>, line 1
    & C:/Python311/python.exe "d:/My Files/Python Files/Python Practice/Chapter7_Q1.py
    ^
```

what did mistake i do

Comment: You can't run python via `python script.py` from within Python's own interpreter. You have to launch it via a command prompt. It looks like you're typing what's supposed to be a command prompt command straight into a Python interpreter.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28753834/5165980)

Comment: you don;t need to do `i = i + 1`. your for loop is already iterating `i`

Comment: Thank you Sembei Norimaki, Sorry, Random Davis I could'nt understand you